# Date as a map key in YAML property file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

How can I bind date value into Java map key from YAML property with Spring Boot?

YAML property file:

```
settings:
  calendar:
    2018-06-04: 2018-06-25
    2018-07-15: 2018-07-20
```

Properties class:

Purpose of the `calendar` map is to translate from one date to another.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "settings")
public class CalendarSettings {

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private Map<LocalDate, LocalDate> calendar = new HashMap<>();

  public Map<LocalDate, LocalDate> getCalendar() {
    return calendar;
  }

  public void setCalendar(
    Map<LocalDate, LocalDate> calendar) {
    this.calendar = calendar;
  }
}
```

With this setup I am receiving following exception:

```
Property: settings.null
Value: 2018-06-04
Reason: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'null'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate': 
no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I am struggling with how to annotate calendar property in `CalendarSettings.class` – if it is possible. Or how to create some kind of de-serializer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run the application in debug mode, you could see the following exception being thrown:

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-06-04' could not be parsed at index 4
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser.parse(TemporalAccessorParser.java:69) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser.parse(TemporalAccessorParser.java:46) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService$ParserConverter.convert(FormattingConversionService.java:200) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
```

The reason why this fails is due to the default parser ([`TemporalAccessorParser`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/TemporalAccessorParser.html)) using localized date converters to map the `String` to a `LocalDate`. To solve this issue, you could write your own converter:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class LocalDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate convert(String timestamp) {
        return LocalDate.parse(timestamp);
    }
}
```

If you register this component with the `@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding` annotation, it will be picked up when parsing the application properties. The [`LocalDate.parse(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method uses the `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` converter, which should work fine in your case.